# Integrate FOSOAuthServerBundle with FOSUserBundle

Tags: api, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I try to add FOSOAuthServerBundle in my Symfony project to protect my API, with FOSUserBundle. This [link](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/) is helpful but I don't sure about the workflow to replace his user provider with FOSUser, in addition I don't have the same result like him. Do you have some indications for me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found, thanks for your awesome answers !

If you want, the link (http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/16/oauth2-explained-part-1-principles-and-terminology/) I provide finally help me, juste change some lines in his code (for FOSUser) and read slowly what he try to explain.

Happy dev